# Watermark Category Images with Brand Logo

Tags: magento-1.9, image, module, product-images

I'd like to add a watermark to each small image (but *only* in the category listing page) that is based on the manufacturer attribute.   I don't want to alter the small image for that product on other pages.

I've thought about setting a watermark for small images and overriding the image file, but that will add the watermark to all small images for that product (which might be shown on other pages).

Is there a somewhat easy way to do this without creating a custom module?

Comment: You may add a layer using CSS, it easier to add watermark.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method for this, you just have to edit the category template, so that your image rendering adds a watermark:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::setWatermark
```

Comment: Stupid people, please start adding comments if you have a problem with post, so I can fix it and learn!

Comment: nice comment, i liked it......